# How to retrieve data from a connected Bluetooth service using BluetoothManager on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

So I finally managed to connect a heartmonitor to my iPhone 5 running iOS 7.0.4, using the private BluetoothManager framework similar to [this tutorial](http://www.pocketmagic.net/2012/07/bluetooth-and-ios-use-bluetooth-in-your-iphone-apps/). Looking to connect to any service (0xFFFFFFFF), the framework detects the service 0x00002000 (no clue what that is, can't find it anywhere) and manages to connect with it.

```
2014-02-13 14:58:41.640 HeartRate[1192:60b] BTM: connecting to device "Heartman_C152" 00:A0:96:20:3D:CD
2014-02-13 14:58:42.042 HeartRate[1192:60b] BTM: attempting to connect to service 0x00002000 on device "Heartman_C152" 00:A0:96:20:3D:CD
2014-02-13 14:58:42.545 HeartRate[1192:60b] BTM: connection to service 0x00002000 on device "Heartman_C152" 00:A0:96:20:3D:CD succeeded
2014-02-13 14:58:42.550 HeartRate[1192:60b] ____________________ CONNECTION SUCCESSFUL
2014-02-13 14:58:42.552 HeartRate[1192:60b] Connected Services Count: 1
2014-02-13 14:58:42.554 HeartRate[1192:60b] Connected Service(s): 8192
2014-02-13 14:58:46.643 HeartRate[1192:60b] Devices connected: (
    "\"Heartman_C152\" 00:A0:96:20:3D:CD"
)
```

If I leave it like that, the device gets lost again after several seconds. I guess that's because I'm not doing anything with that connection.

**So how do I get to listen to the service I am connected to?**

Thanks a lot for any answers and tips, been working on this for hours without progress. Can't seem to find appropriate API in the *BluetoothManager* or *BluetoothDevice* headers. Do I need to create sockets or something like that?

P.S.: Can't use GameKit as I'm not connecting two iOS devices and not CoreBluetooth either since this Heartmonitor is not BLE compatible.